# Powershell Regex over array

Tags: regex, powershell

I am getting the following error when trying to apply the following regex on this Exchange command.

```
@(Get-ExchangeServer | Format-List AdminDisplayVersion) | % { [regex]::Match($_, "^\sVersion (\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s").Success }
```

---

The command `Get-ExchangeServer | Format-List AdminDisplayVersion` returns the following:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ExchangeServer | Format-List AdminDisplayVersion


AdminDisplayVersion : Version 14.0 (Build 442.3)

AdminDisplayVersion : Version 14.0 (Build 442.3)
```

And when applying the regex to it I get all false:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>@(Get-ExchangeServer | Format-List AdminDisplayVersion) | % { [regex]::Match($_, "^\sVersion (\
d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s").Success }
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

---

Any pointers as of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdminDisplayVersion is a Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ServerVersion object which has all of the version parts as properties. You can get the values directly without having to resort to string manipulation. If the Build part is what you;re looking for:

```
Get-ExchangeServer | Foreach-Object {$_.AdminDisplayVersion.Build}
```

Based on the above you can create a query like:

```
Get-ExchangeServer | Where-Object {$_.AdminDisplayVersion.Build -eq 123}
```

Comment: Cool! that's fantastic, a lot more practical!

Answer (score 0):

You have limited your regex to start with " Version" (`^\sVersion`). Here is correct one:

`% { [regex]::Match($_, "\sVersion (\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s").Success }`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your pattern in:

```
"\sVersion (\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?)\s"
```